# rnn.trainr time dimension for X [and Y]

Tags: r, recurrent-neural-network

Ref: https://github.com/bquast/rnn

According to the documentation, the X and Y variables should be:

> Usage
>
> ```
> trainr(Y, X, learningrate, learningrate_decay = 1, momentum = 0,
>   hidden_dim = c(10), network_type = "rnn", numepochs = 1,
>   sigmoid = c("logistic", "Gompertz", "tanh"), use_bias = F,
>   batch_size = 1, seq_to_seq_unsync = F, update_rule = "sgd",
>   epoch_function = c(epoch_print, epoch_annealing), loss_function = loss_L1,
> ...)
> ```
>
> Arguments
>
> Y - array of output values, dim 1: samples (must be equal to dim 1 of
>   X), dim 2: time (must be equal to dim 2 of X), dim 3: variables (could
>   be 1 or more, if a matrix, will be coerce to array)
>   X - array of
>   input values, dim 1: samples, dim 2: time, dim 3: variables (could be
>   1 or more, if a matrix, will be coerce to array)create 3d array: dim
>   1:  samples; dim 2: time; dim 3: variables

I don't really understand the example given

```
X1 = sample(0:127, 7000, replace=TRUE)
X2 = sample(0:127, 7000, replace=TRUE)
# create training response numbers
Y <- X1 + X2

# convert to binary
X1 <- int2bin(X1, length=8)
X2 <- int2bin(X2, length=8)
Y  <- int2bin(Y,  length=8)

# create 3d array: dim 1: samples; dim 2: time; dim 3: variables
X <- array( c(X1,X2), dim=c(dim(X1),2) )

# train the model
model <- trainr(Y=Y,
            X=X,
            learningrate   =  0.1,
            hidden_dim     = 10   )
```

Can anyone please explain the ***'dim 2: time' dimension*** of the X and Y array?

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure you figured this out given the age of the post, but I also found the documentation confusing and wanted to provide an answer for any others searching for more.

The example code takes two inputs and converts them to 8-bit sequences.  These two 8-bit sequences are the features in your model, and Y is what you are trying to predict (which should be easy as it is the 8-bit version of the sum).

RNNs are used to predict results over time, so each row of your data represents the next step in time.  There are 5000 rows in the example, each one having 2 features that are 8 bits deep.  So what the function is looking for is an array that is 5000*8*2, 5000 observations of 2 variables that are 8 bits deep. The target (Y) does not have any features, so its dimensions are 5000*8*1

Calling the 2nd dimension the time dimension is pretty confusing if you are used to dealing with R data.frames, but if you test the example code, it is clear that this is what the function requires.

Hope this helps... somebody..